# Solve an algrebraic equation

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=e^{\tan {x}}+3^{\sin {x}}$ and $g(x)=2-2010x-\arctan{x}$, I have to find the roots of the equation $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x \neq \frac{\pi}{2} (2k+1)$. My basic idea is that $f(x)$ is a periodic function (with period $-2\pi $), since $g(x)$ is a non periodic function. For the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$, the common root is $0$, which is the only real root i think. I tried to use the same idea to solve the system $\arctan {x}=\tan {y}+\tan{z},\arctan {y}=\tan {x}+\tan{z},\arctan {z}=\tan {x}+\tan{y}$, without success. Am i right?

Comment: Do you need the roots exactly, or is an approximation okay? There are infinitely many roots, and all but $x=0$ are nontrivial to identify exactly.

Comment: an approximation

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, $f$ is periodic while $g$ is not. Unfortunately, this does not allow us to conclude anything about the roots of $f-g$. However, we have $f(x) = e^{\tan(x)} + 3^{\sin(x)} > 3^{-1}$, and this is the best bound we can have, as $\lim_{x \to \frac{-\pi}{2}^+} f(x) = 3^{-1}$, since $\tan(x) \to -\infty$ and $\sin(x) \to -1$ here. Meanwhile, since $|\arctan(x)| \leq |x|$, $g(x)$ is between $2-2009x$ and $2-2011x$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular, $g(x) < 3^{-1}$ for $x >\frac{5}{3*2009}$, so there are no solutions in this region. We can improve this to no solutions for $x>0$ by noting that $f(0)=g(0)=2$ and that $f$ is increasing on $(0,\frac{5}{3*2009})$ while $g$ is decreasing (as $g$ is always decreasing).

Since the left one-sided limit $\lim_{x \to (2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}^\pm} f(x)$ is always $+\infty$  while the right is either $3^{-1}$ or $3$, and since $g(x)>3$ for $x<-\frac{\pi}{2}$, an application of the intermediate value theorem to $f-g$ will tell you that there exists a root on every interval $((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2},(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2})$ for $k$ a negative integer. Since $g(x)>>1$ on each of these intervals, one can show that intersection points must occur on a region where $f$ is increasing, giving that the root on each interval is unique.

Writing $x_k =(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $k$ a negative integer and noting that, since $g(x)>>1$ on $(x_{k-1},x_k)$, the root $y_k$ on this interval must occur very close to $x_k$ (where $f \to +\infty$), we may approximate $\sin(y_k) \approx \sin(x_k) = (-1)^k$ and $g(y_k) \approx g(x_k)$, giving
$$ e^{\tan(y_k)}+3^{(-1)^k} \approx f(y_k) = g(y_k) \approx g(x_k)= 2-2010x_k - \arctan(x_k)$$
Or
$$y_k \approx x_k-\frac{\pi}{2}+ \arctan(\ln(2-3^{(-1)^k}-\arctan(x_k)-2010x_k))$$
Where the term $x_k-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is added to use the inverse to the tangent function on $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ instead of on $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Since all of the RHS terms inside the logarithm are very small compared to $2010x_k$, you'd do essentially just as well to approximate

$$y_k \approx x_k-\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan \left ( \ln(-x_k)+\ln(2010) \right) $$
This approximation is fairly good, as it numerically yields $f(y_k) \approx g(y_k)$ within $1$ percent by $k=-4$ and improves to $.02$ percent by $k=-100$, with the maximal error of about $7$ percent at $k=-1$.

Comment: Important edit: I realized that I didn't actually need to approximate the tangent function via the Laurent series, given the other approximations that were necessary to make the algebra doable.